# AES CBC with password iterations function port from C# to Node

Tags: c#, node.js, aes

i need to port the following C# function to Node

```
public static string Decrypt(string CipherText, string Password, string Salt, string InitialVector, int PasswordIterations, string HashAlgorithm = "SHA1", int KeySize = 256) 
{
    var InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
    var SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
    var CipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CipherText);
    var DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
    var KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
    var SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    var PlainTextBytes = new byte[CipherTextBytes.Length];
    var ByteCount = 0;

    using (var Decryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes))
    {
        using (var MemStream = new MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes))
        {
            using (var CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                ByteCount = CryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
                MemStream.Close();
                CryptoStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    SymmetricKey.Clear();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PlainTextBytes, 0, ByteCount);
}
```

I have been trying so far with various Node modules like mcrypt, aes-js, js-rijndael, rinjndael-js, crypto, crypto-js, cryptojs etc, but i am unable to find a way or understand how i need to approach this.

What confuses me specially is how to do the password iterations step. Can anyone suggest a node module that supports it or a way to implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not just gonna solve your work. Be specific about a problem you have. You just want us to "solve it all"..

Comment: Just need help with the password iterations step and finding a node module that supports it i assume. As for what i've tried, i said i did try implementations with various modules.